# Data Binding Order of Operations for Caliburn Micro Xamarin

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin, caliburn.micro

What is the "Order of Operations" (OOP) for Data Binding in Caliburn.Micro Xamarin Android (Mono.Android)?

PS: a tutorial that explains/compares how binding occurs in Caliburn Micro Standard/WPF, Caliburn Micro Android & Caliburn Micro iOS (ie Caliburn.Micro Xamarin) would be very useful and a nice introduction into Caliburn Micro Xamarin.

For regular Caliburn.Micro the OOP for Binding is (correct me if I am wrong):

- Declare Field in ViewModel
- On Field Set: call `NotifyOfPropertyChange(..)`
- Bind View to ViewModel using the XAML attribute `x:Name`

I've inspected the example projects `Hello.Xamarin` and `HubBrowser` and I think I have a bit of an idea how it works but it looks like there is ALOT of setup required. For Caliburn.Micro Xamarin Android is the Binding OOP something like...?

- Extend the `NotifyPropertyChanged` method. Not sure why...maybe so it works for Android? We produce a static class called `NotifyPropertyChangedExtensions`
- Declare Field in ViewModel (same as standard CM)
- On Field Set: call `NotifyOfPropertyChange(..)` (same as standard CM)
- Give all View widgets a unique id `android:id`
- On View (Activity) creation: bind View widgets to ViewModel Fields somehow??

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the OOP you have indicated for the Windows flavor of binding occurs under the hood, the system is ViewModel first meaning everything starts with a viewmodel from there we look to see if we have a View with the same namespace and name.  If we find it, great, now mash them together with a binding operation essentially setting the Datacontext of the view with the instance of the viewmodel.  Otherwise, fail give the resultant screen a default blank stare back at you :(.

Since the stuff associated with binding in Xamarin / Native is slightly different hence some of the features will probably come at a later date with more tutorials / samples as people get a chance to road test the code.

Link has some of the stuff yet to complete and stuff that is complete with explanations as to why or why not. 
https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/142